# Is $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(2x)}+\sin(x)-\cos(x)$ strictly positive?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I would like to have an advice for this exercise.

> Let $x\in[0,\pi]$ For which values of $x$ this function $$f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(2x)}+\sin(x)-\cos(x)$$ is strictly positive ?

I tried to compute the derivative, i get so far $$f'(x)=\frac{\cos(x)\cos(2x)+2\sin(x)\sin(2x)}{\cos(2x)^2}+\cos(x)-\sin(x).$$

Using the fact that $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin(x)^2$ we have $$f'(x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(2x)^2}+\cos(x)-\sin(x)=\cos(x)\bigl(\frac{1}{\cos(2x)^2}+1-\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\bigr).$$  I'm not sure I simplify my problem. Any ideas ?

Comment: How do you define $f(\pi/4)$?

Comment: @Nameless it's an exam question, I think I have to say by myself that $f(\pi/4)$ is not defined.

Comment: My apologies, that question was red herring. I thought you were asking how to show it is continuous.

Comment: @Nameless no problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: write $$f(x) = \dfrac{\ldots}{\cos(2x)}$$ and simplify the numerator.  Then look at the intervals between points where the numerator or denominator is $0$.

EDIT:

$$ f(x) = \dfrac{\cos(x) \left(2 \sin(x) \cos(x) - 2 \cos(x)^2 + 1\right)}{\cos(2x)} = \dfrac{\cos(x) \left(\sin(2x) - \cos(2x)\right)}{\cos(2x)}$$

Comment: When you say simplify, did you use $c(2x)=c^2-s^2$ or $c(2x)=1-2s^2$ ? Using the first one we have $f(x)=s+(c-s)(c+s)(s-c)$, is it what did you do ?